# Call method on all the existing instances of UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, protocols

I want to be able to allow the user to change some properties of the graphical user interface immediately through all the app. To achieve that, I thought about creating a protocol like

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func changeProperties()
}
```

so each UIViewController can change those properties in its own way and  then call this method in all the current instantiated controllers.

However, I don't know if this is possible. My first idea was to access the most root controller of the app, and then iterate through all the child recursively calling the method. Something like

```
func updatePropertiesFrom(_ vc: UIViewController) {
    for child in vc.childViewControllers {
        if let target = child as? MyProtocol {
            target.changeProperties()
        }

        updatePropertiesFrom(child)
    }
}

let appRootController = ...
updatePropertiesFrom(appRootController)
```

I don't know how to get that appRootController and I would like to know if there's any more elegant way for doing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the app's root controller with:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow.rootViewController
```

Of course this assumes the current key window is the one with your app's root controller.

You could also access the `window` property of your app delegate and get the `rootViewController` from that window.

Your general approach is valid. There is no other "more elegant" way to walk your app's current view controllers. Though you should also traverse presented view controllers as well as the child view controllers.

However, a simpler solution might be to post a notification using `NotificationCenter` and have all of your view controllers respond accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NotificationCenter`. E.g. define a notification name:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let changeViewProperties = Notification.Name(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".changeViewProperties")
}
```

And your various view controllers can then register to be notified when this notification is posted:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .changeViewProperties, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
    // do something here
}
```

(If you're supporting iOS versions prior to iOS 9, make sure to remove your observer in `deinit`.)

And to post the notification when you want to initiate the change:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .changeViewProperties, object: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a central dispatcher and having each `UIViewController` register with it.

Example:

```
class MyDispatcher{
    static let sharedInstance = MyDispatcher()

    var listeners: [MyProtocol]()

    private init() {}

    public func dispatch(){
        for listener in listeners{
            listener.changeProperties()
        }
    }  
}
```

From each `UIViewController` you want to update the properties, you call `MyDispatcher.sharedInstance.listeners.append(self)`. When you want to update the properties, you call `MyDispatcher.sharedInstance.dispatch()`.

Comment: And that is why apple came up with Notifications.